# Relationships between absolute Galois groups

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $F/K$ be a finite Galois extension of fields (of characteristic 0 if it makes a difference). Let $G_F$ and $G_K$ denote their absolute Galois groups.

**Q: What is the relationship between $G_F$, $G_K$ and $Gal(F/K)$, thought of as abstract groups?**

This must be elementary, but I keep getting tangled up in confusion trying to explicitly work out the various homomorphisms and indeterminacies involved. There is a homomorphism from $G_F$ to $G_K$, the image of which is basically everything except $Gal(F/K)$, but I can't seem to get any additional clarity. I suspect that I'm either missing something straight forward or it's hard to say in general. I've been out of the pure maths world for some years so probably the former!

EDIT: my naive guess from finite Galois theory (that $G_F$ is isomorphic to an open subgroup of $G_K$ with the quotient being $Gal(F/K)$) seems to be false due to the example in comments. But I might be confused here too.

Comment: $G_K$ has an open normal subgroup isomorphic to $G_F$ with the quotient being isomorphic to $\text{Gal}(L/K)$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Is that really true? If I take $K=\mathbb{Q}_2$ and $F$ the extension from adjoining $i$ then the pro-2 quotients of $G_K$ and $G_F$ are $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{4Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^3$ respectively (unless I made a mistake), and I can't see how the former can be realised as a subgroup of the latter.

Comment: sorry, above should read "pro-2 quotients of abelianisations of $G_K$ and $G_F$.

Comment: While $G_F$ is a subgroup of $G_K$, I see no reason why the $2$-power part of the Abelianisation of $G_F$ should be a subgroup of the $2$-power part of the Abelianisation of $G_K$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I guess I assumed that the basic Galois correspondences giving the answer in the arbitrary case would translate also to the setting when assuming abelian 2-extensions, since both of these are `well-behaved' field extensions. If that is wrong, what breaks down? I appreciate your help so far btw!

Comment: Are you interested in the Galois groups $G_F$ etc., or are you interested in these profinite $2$-groups? If the latter, you should have asked a question about them.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I am really interested in the pro-2 groups. I mistakenly assumed the reasoning should somehow be equivalent but I guess that's wrong. Should I make a new question or edit this one?

Comment: One has a natural embedding $G_F\to G_K$. This induces a map $G_F\G_F'\to G_K/G_K'$ on their Abelianisations, but that map need not be injective. Even for finite groups, the induced map need't be injective.

Comment: Is it then in general not possible to relate the image and kernel of the induced map to $Gal(F/K)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real confusion here, alluded to in comments, was clarified in the following: [Galois correspondence for pro-p extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800644/galois-correspondence-for-pro-p-extensions)