# Galois correspondence for pro-p extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am experiencing persistent confusion about the Galois correspondence when restricted to pro-$p$ extensions of a field $K$ (of characteristic $0$), $p$ a prime.

My naive expectation is that, because pro-$p$ extensions are `well-behaved' (closed under forming subgroups, quotients, extensions and products), the usual Galois correspondence should follow through, i.e. pro-$p$ extensions of $K$ correspond (bijectively) with quotients of $G_K(p)$, the maximal pro-$p$ quotient of the absolute Galois group of $K$, or equivalently $Gal(K(p)/K)$ where $K(p)$ is the maximal pro-$p$ extension of $K$.

This expectation leads me to think that if $F/K$ is a finite pro-$p$ extension, then $G_F(p)$ can be realised as a subgroup of $G_K(p)$ with the quotient being isomorphic to $Gal(F/K)$, by analogy to the case with arbitrary Galois extensions. However, this seems to be wrong, because work by Demushkin-Labute-Serre showed that if we e.g. take $K=\mathbb{Q}_2$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-1}))$, then the pro-$2$ groups can be computed, with explicit generators and relations. Crucially, the rank of $G_K(2)$ here equals 3, while that of $G_F(2)$ equals 4, so surely $G_F(2)$ cannot be realised as a subgroup of $G_K(2)$. Rather, $G_K(2)$ looks like a quotient of $G_F(2)$.

**What is the general relationship between $G_F(p)$, $G_K(p)$ and $Gal(F/K)$ for an arbitrary pro-$p$ extension $F$ of $K$? Why does my naive expectation fail, or why was my expectation confused in the first place?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "products" under "well-behaved," but pro-$p$ extensions aren't closed under [compositum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_fields#Compositum_of_fields), so they're not maximally nice. As a simple example, let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^3 - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. $K$ has subextensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} \omega)$ of degree $3$ and their compositum is $K$, which has degree $6$. The corresponding group-theoretic fact is that the intersection of subgroups of $p$-power index need not have $p$-power index.

On the other hand I also don't know what you mean by the rank of a nonabelian group. For any of the meanings I can think of that might plausibly be relevant, it's not true that if $G$ is a subgroup of $H$ then the rank of $G$ must be less than or equal to the rank of $H$.

Comment: +1, in particular, it's not true that a subgroup of a group with 4 (topological) generators must have <= 4 (topological) generators

Comment: Right. In fact already the free group $F_2$ on two generators admits the free group $F_{\infty}$ on countably many generators as a subgroup!

Comment: It's clear now my confusion was due to my totally wrong assumption that the rank (by which I meant the minimal number of topological generators) was respected in subgroups. The $F_2$ example shows just how wrong! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks both, and apologies for the vagueness. The post should have read 'the class of finite p-groups are well behaved', with 'product' meaning 'direct product'. So on the field side this means Galois extensions, with it being true that the compositum of two Galois p-extensions is a p-extension.

Answer (score 3):

There is much vagueness in your definitions/assertions about the Galois correspondence in a profinite extension $L/K$. Let us start again from the fundamental notions :

(1) To speak of $Gal(L/K)$, you should assume (as practically everybody does) that the extension $L/K$ is Galois. In your query about the relationship between $G_F(p), G_K(p)$ and $Gal(F/K)$, the first two pro-$p$-extensions are automatically Galois by maximality, but I think that  you  assume implicitly that $F/K$ is Galois.

(2) The profinite Galois correspondence states that, for a profinite Galois extension $L/K$ with group $G$, there is a bijection (built in the usual way) between the set of all the sub-extensions $F/K$ of $L/K$ and the set of all **closed** subgroups of $G$. This is a genuine limitation because, practically by definition, $G$ is the projective limit of the quotients $G/U$, where $U$ runs through all **open** normal subgroups of $G$. Recall that a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is open iff $H$ is closed and has finite index in $G$. Moreover, if $G$ is topologically of finite type (i.e. $G$ admits a subroup of finite type which is dense), then its subgroups of finite index are open.

(3) In the last question (which worries you because of a contradiction), you don't need the subextension $F/K$ to be Galois, only that it has finite degree. You take for granted the erroneous assertion that the "rank"of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ (even of finite idex) should be less than that of $G$. But:

(a) We must first define the "rank" $d(G)$ of a pro-$p$-group $G$. In view of the last sentence of (2), $d(G)$ can be defined, if $G$ is topologically of finite type, as the minimal number of topological generators of $G$ if it is finite, $\infty$ otherwise. Finiteness does not always occur, even in examples coming from number theory. The pro-$p$-analog of Burnside's basis theorem for (finite) $p$-groups tells us that $d(G)$ is the $\mathbf F_p$-dimension of $G/[G,G]G^p$ viewed as a $\mathbf F_p$ vector space. When $G= G_K(p)$ and $K$ is a local $p$-adic field, local class field theory allows to show that $d(G)$ is finite (actually explicit formulas are available). When $K$ is a number field, $d(G_K(p))$ is no longer finite in general, but global class field theory again allows to show that finiteness occurs for certain quotients of $G_K(p)$ defined by imposing adequate ramification conditions. For all this, see e.g. H. Koch's book "Galois Theory of $p$-extensions", chap.9-11.

(b) Assuming that $G$ is a pro-$p$-group with $d(G)$ finite and $H$ a subgroup of finite index, the explicit formulas alluded to in (a) give $d(H)$. For example, if $K$ is a local field of degree $n$ over $\mathbf Q_p$, then $d(G_K(p))=n+1+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon =1$ (resp.$0$) if $K$ contains (resp. does not contain) a primitive $p$-th root of unity, and analogously $d(G_F(p))$. It follows that $d(G_F(p))-d(G_K(p))=n([F:K]-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response, and apologies for the lack of sufficient detail in my question (yes I assumed Galois and meant min. number of topological generators). My erroneous assumption about ranks and subgroups was the big source of confusion here, so I've accepted the above answer instead of yours, as it came first. But this was much appreciated as well.